# run multiple threads (each with own application context) and shutdown gracefully

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I have a multithreaded app which I'm redesigning with SpringBoot 1.5. Please look at the following example:

```
@Service
@Lazy
class MyService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

    private String account;

    private boolean stopped = false;
    private boolean processing;

    public MyService(String account) {
        logger.debug("MyService constructor");
        this.account = account;
    }

    public void run() {
        logger.debug("starting thread " + account);        
        while(!stopped) {
            try {
                processing = false;
                Thread.sleep(5000); // awaiting some service response
                processing = true;
                Thread.sleep(3000); // processing service response
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error(null,e);
            }
        }
        logger.debug("finished gracefully");
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopped = true;
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    private static final String[] accounts = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String account : accounts) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, account);
                BeanFactory factory = context.getBeanFactory();
                MyService service = factory.getBean(MyService.class, account);

                context.addApplicationListener(event -> {
                    if(event instanceof ContextClosedEvent) {
                        service.stop();
                        // context.registerShutdownHook();
                        // context.close();
                    }
                });
                service.run();
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.com.example = DEBUG
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multicontext-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I came up with multi-context configuration because I want to autowire "singleton" scoped beans which have thread-specific data.

Questions:

1. Is it a correct way to create application context per thread?
2. Why can I see duplicated log messages (thread number squared times)? For example, "MyService constructor" message is printed 9 times when 3 threads are running, instead of 3 times (one instance per context).
3. How to shutdown each service thread gracefully, taking into account that no need to wait if the service is awaiting response and not processing it? Currently, I can't see "finished gracefully" message when the app stopped.
4. Do I need to call `context.close()` or `context.registerShutdownHook()` or both? when I should do that and what will happen wouldn't I do that?

Comment: I am wondering, what is the use case for state-ful singleton beans? This is a pattern that I never came across in Spring boot before, just curious.

Comment: What about HttpClient which keeps authentication token which has some lifetime? Or would it be better to authenticate multiple times? as many as instances of the bean is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve a graceful shutdown, I'll show one by using a Scheduled trick (which I learned somewhere from StackOverflow).

The Scheduled trick starts a task at application context start but the task is never scheduled again (`initialDelay = 0L, fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE`), effectively turning the scheduled task into a background service. Spring schedules the task and you can configure Spring how to handle scheduled tasks via the `SchedulingConfigurer` which gives you control over the scheduled tasks, including the shutdown.

The normal manner of stopping running tasks is to interrupt them, so I used that to stop the service. But you can still use the `ContextClosedEvent` to stop the service from running if you really need to.

Since the scheduled task is started async, there is no longer a need to start application contexts in a separate thread in the main method.

I tested on the command line using:

`mvn clean spring-boot:run`

and

`mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`

`java -jar target\[app].jar`

Press "ctrl-c" to initiate shutdown.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class App implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    private static final AtomicInteger ctxCount = new AtomicInteger();

    private static final String[] accounts = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Arrays.stream(accounts).forEach(account -> {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, account);
            context.getBeanFactory().getBean(MyService.class, account);
        });
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7779
        final String prefix = "app-" + ctxCount.incrementAndGet() + "-mcsch-";
        log.debug("Creating task scheduler {}", prefix);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(prefix);
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(20);
        return scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        log.debug("Setting task scheduler.");
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
    }

    @Service
    @Lazy
    static class MyService {

        private String account;

        public MyService(String account) {
            log.debug("{} - MyService constructor", account);
            this.account = account;
        }

        // trick to "run at startup"
        @Scheduled(initialDelay = 0L, fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE)
        public void run() {
            boolean stopped = false;
            while(!stopped) {
                try {
                    log.debug("{} - sleeping", account);        
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.debug("{} - sleep interrupted", account);
                    stopped = true;
                }
            }
            log.debug("{} - finished gracefully", account);
        }
    } // MyService

}
```